# Select Case fall through in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a select case statement in conjunction with a function to create fall through in VBA, but I can't seem to figure out how it should be structured. Here's what I'm looking for it to do:

1. Check if row values 1 & 10 have same unique ID (if not: 1&9;1&8,1&7,...,1&2)

   1a. If row values 1 & 10 have same unique ID then all rows inbetween do as well

   2a. Even though all rows have same unique ID, it *does not mean that the cells I want to check afterward are all the same* -- for example: rows 1,3,4,7,8,10 may have blank cells while rows 2,5,9 are not blank. In order to determine that, it has to go through each row from 10 through 1 to determine this. One row does not affect another; any/all/none of the rows from 1-10 can have blank cells despite them all having the same unique ID.
2. check for blank cell in all rows between and including the first and last
3. Concatenate unique IDs of all rows with blank cells.

The issue is this: I will need 10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2 nested select statements for the first check alone.

---

Here is a psuedocode example:

Begin First loop (first range: Excel sheet rows 2-12; 10 rows):

Rows 1 & 10 have same unique id

Check row 10 for blank cells

No blank cells in row 10

Check row 9 for blank cells

Blank cells found -> add info to string

Check row 8 for blank cells

Blank cells found -> add info to string

Check row 7 for blank cells

No blank cells found

Check row 6 for blank cells

Blank cells found - > add info to string

Check row 5 for blank cells

....

No more blank cells found

Begin Second loop (second range: Excel sheet rows 12-14; 3 rows):

Cells 12 and 14 match

Check row 14 for blank cells

Blank cells found -> add info to separate string

Check row 13 for blank cells

No Blank cells found

Check row 12 for blank cells

No blank cells found

---

My current code is below:

```
Sub selectcasetryagain()
Dim c As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

lastRow = Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))

For i = 2 To lastRow
    Set c = r.Cells(i, 6)
    Select Case c.Value
        Case SelectCaseFallThru(c)

    End Select
Next i

End Sub

Option Explicit
Public c, r As Range
Public i As Integer
Public lastRow, lastCol As Long
Public RMissing As Variant

Function SelectCaseFallThru(Optional c As Variant, Optional d As Variant)
    If c.Value = c.Offset(10, 0).Value Then
        Debug.Print c.Value & " - " & c.Offset(10, 0).Value
        If IsEmpty(c.Offset(0, 46)).Value And IsEmpty(c.Offset(0, 47)).Value Then
            RMissing = c.Offset(0, 42).Value
        i = i + 10
    ElseIf c.Value = c.Offset(9, 0).Value Then
        Debug.Print c.Value & " - " & c.Offset(9, 0).Value
        i = i + 9
    ElseIf c.Value = c.Offset(8, 0).Value Then
        Debug.Print c.Value & " - " & c.Offset(8, 0).Value
        i = i + 8
    ElseIf c.Value = c.Offset(7, 0).Value Then
        Debug.Print c.Value & " - " & c.Offset(7, 0).Value
        i = i + 7
    ElseIf c.Value = c.Offset(6, 0).Value Then
        Debug.Print c.Value & " - " & c.Offset(6, 0).Value
        i = i + 6
    ElseIf c.Value = c.Offset(5, 0).Value Then
        Debug.Print c.Value & " - " & c.Offset(5, 0).Value
        i = i + 5
    ElseIf c.Value = c.Offset(4, 0).Value Then
        Debug.Print c.Value & " - " & c.Offset(4, 0).Value
        i = i + 4
    ElseIf c.Value = c.Offset(3, 0).Value Then
        Debug.Print c.Value & " - " & c.Offset(3, 0).Value
        i = i + 3
    ElseIf c.Value = c.Offset(2, 0).Value Then
        Debug.Print c.Value & " - " & c.Offset(2, 0).Value
        i = i + 2
    ElseIf c.Value = c.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        Debug.Print c.Value & " - " & c.Offset(1, 0).Value
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If


End Function
```

Comment: I don't understand this statement "I will need 10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2 nested select statements for the first check alone". Don't you just need 10?

Comment: Looks to me like you're overthinking it - I think you could achieve all of this with two nested loops

Comment: All rows between the two values are the same (e.g., 1&10=same, then 2-9=same as 1&10). I want each row checked individually and its unique id added to a string. If the loop hits on one then it won't check the other conditions, as far as I understand it? This means that it has to go a layer deeper on each hit to successfully gather all of the unique ids for the rows with the blank cell?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, am struggling to follow this?

Comment: @sjr https://prnt.sc/i1takf

Comment: seems like just one For loop to find the last value that is equal to the first, and another For loop to check if all of the values before it are equal to the first value too.

Comment: @slai not all will necessarily be equal. It could be the case that 10,8,6,2 are but the rest are not.

Comment: then you may need to explain 1a better, and probably needs few good examples. The screenshot seems to make it even more confusing.

Comment: @Slai I've updated the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your `selectcasefallthrough` to make it more flexible, and added some additional comments. Since I wasn't sure which section of your psuedocode was currently giving you trouble, I didn't add any additional capabilities. However, I can edit them in, once I know which psuedocode step you're currently stuck on.

```
Sub selectcasetryagain()
Dim c As Range 'Will no longer access Global c
Dim r As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

lastRow = Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))

For i = 2 To lastRow
    Set c = r.Cells(i, 6)
    Select Case c.Value
        Case SelectCaseFallThru(10, c) ' Added in row number to make it variable

    End Select
Next i

End Sub

Option Explicit
Public c, r As Range 'Note: currently Global c is defined as a Variant
Public i As Integer
Public lastRow, lastCol As Long
Public RMissing As Variant

'This function does not currently return anything.
Function SelectCaseFallThru(maxRowNum as Integer, Optional c As Variant, Optional d As Variant) 'This Function will use the Optional c, not the Global c
    Dim counter as Integer
    Dim found as Boolean

    For counter = maxRowNum to 1 step -1
        If c.Value = c.Offset(counter, 0).Value Then
            Debug.Print c.Value & " - " & c.Offset(counter, 0).Value
            If IsEmpty(c.Offset(0, 46)).Value And IsEmpty(c.Offset(0, 47)).Value and counter = maxRowNum Then 'added check for counter
                RMissing = c.Offset(0, 42).Value
            End if
            i = i + counter
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next counter

    If not found Then Exit Function

End Function
```